# Helping my nephew with 8th grade math

Tags: algebra-precalculus, square-numbers

Helping my nephew with math. I have no clue what exactly he’s learned and how to help him entirely. He has a problem Find the square root:
-$\sqrt {1600}$

The negative symbol is outside of the square root. What would the answer be?

Comment: Maybe start with $\,-\,\sqrt{1600} = -\,\sqrt{16}\,\sqrt{100}\,$.

Comment: Why can't you just be honest with him and tell him you don't know this stuff?

Comment: Eighth graders are expected to know prime factorisation and basic exponent rules. $\\-\sqrt{1600}\\ = -1\times \sqrt{2^6\times 5^2} \\ =-1\times \left(2^6\times 5^2\right)^{1/2} \\=-1\times 2^{6/2} \times 5^{2/2} \\= -1\times 2^3 \times 5^1\\ =-40$

Comment: @Nothingspecial thank you so much! that’s what i needed to know. I didn’t wanna go on and explain stuff he doesn’t need to know or tell him something wrong. I appreciate your response so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GERMDAS (G = grouping, R = roots) order of operations. Roots are at the same level as exponents, so take the square root first (which is 40), then apply the negative sign, since it's at the same level as subtraction, so your answer is -40.